# Can't see running status indicator Dash to Panel

Tags: 18.04, extension

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on a Dell XPS 15 9560 and I have always used the Dash to Panel extension but after I updated it last week [(this one on omgubuntu)](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/07/dash-to-panel-window-previews-update). I can no longer see the running indicator. I like to have it at the bottom but it seems to have fallen of the screen.

When I set the running indicator to be set at the left, right or top I can see it but in the bottom I can no longer see it it seems. I can't be sure but it seems that the taskbar is shifted a bit downward and that is the reason I can't see the status running indicator.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/eiqRsZP this is how it looks on my computer... hopefully you can see the issue.

Comment: @PRATAP do you have any idea where i could find a fix or something else to try and fix it?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I don't know the setting that would raise the panel a bit. I've looked through the dconf options but can't seem to find it.

Comment: Even fully reinstalling an older version does not fix it.

Comment: I seem to have found the issue, I was using the flat-mix shell theme and using another shell theme fixes the issue. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Installing a different version of the flat-remix shell theme it now fully works. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue eventually was to do with my shell theme. Apparently some shell themes don't play nice with Dash to Panel. Installing a different version of that shell or another shell enitrely fixes the issue. In my case it was flat-remix, and installing another version of that shell (flat-remix-dark-fullPanel) fixed it.